# C++ error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment|

Tags: c++

```
char **v= new char*[n];
    char b=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        while(b)
        {
            int j=0;
            cin>>b;``
            v[i]+j=new char [1]
            *(*(v+i)+j)=b;
            j++;
        }
```

error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment|

Comment: Use indexing instead of arithmetic: `v[i]+j=new char [1];` and it immediately becomes clearer. (The other line is more readable as `v[i][j]=b;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the line you're stopped at is

```
*(v+i)+j=new char [1];
```

Let see what we do here.
First, we calculate some pointer arithmetic to get an address in the memory

```
*(v+i)+j
```

Second, we try to put new value to that memory:

```
new char [1];
```

The only issue here is the address you've calculated is temporary thing, you should remember it inside a variable first (read more about lvalue and rvalue terms, for example, [at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)).

And what if we do something like so?

```
char *p = *(v+i)+j; // get it to lvalue-compatible thing
p = new char [1]; // put a value in
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem, I'll try to figure out he reason of the error now.